# OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: wrong final block length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openssl, caesar-cipher

```
source = ... # encrypted string - Base64.encode64(string)
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('AES-128-ECB')
cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = ['YOUR_CHANNEL_SECRET'].pack('H*')
decoded = Base64.decode64(source)
decrypted = cipher.update(decoded) + cipher.final
```

For YOUR_CHANNEL_SECRET
I convert my secret key in Hex Decimal String

Reference - https://developers.line.me/in_app_web/api-reference#get_token_access_token

I'm getting error on **cipher.final**, I don't know why this error occur and what is the solution?

I follow same that define in the reference link but still getting error.

Comment: Your code looks fine. The problem is the encrypted data should be a multiple of 16 bytes long, and it isn’t. Either you’ve somehow mangled the data before you try to decrypt it, or it was wrong when you received it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead:

```
source = ... # encrypted string - Base64.encode64(string)
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('AES-128-ECB')
cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = ['YOUR_CHANNEL_SECRET'].pack('H*')
decoded = Base64.decode64(source)
decrypted = cipher.update(decoded) + cipher.final
```

I do it like:

```
def decrypt(encrypted_data, key, iv=nil, cipher_type="AES-256-CBC")
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(cipher_type)
  cipher.decrypt
  cipher.key = key
  cipher.iv = iv if iv != nil
  cipher.update([encrypted_data].pack("H*")) + cipher.final
end
```

Comment: Not working - Error on cipher.key and last line. NoMethodError: undefined method `pack' for #<String:0xc531bd0>

Comment: Getting same error - OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: wrong final block length